# Mat-checkbox in Angular throwing 'checked' binding error, what's causing it?

Tags: angular

I'm quite new to Angular environment but here is my problem :

My problem comes from the mat-checkbox element. When i try to bind a boolean to its checked property I get the following error :
"Can't bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-checkbox'".

The html :  `<mat-checkbox [checked]="isChecked" >CheckBox</mat-checkbox>.`

Here is a look at my package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^21.2.6",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^21.2.4",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^21.2.4",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids": "^21.2.8",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^15.0.5",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^15.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.4"
  }
```

Here is also the list of my imports :

```
imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    DatePickerModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    GridModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
],
```

I tried to :

- uninstall and install Angular/cli
- uninstall and install Angular/material
- Changed the order of the imports from the app.module.ts

**Update 1 :**

So just to be sure, i decided to create a new project and start from scratch.
**I created a new Angular project via the cmd  :**
[image: Cmd]

**I then added the angular/material package :**

[image: Installation of angular/material]

Here is my app.module.ts :

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TestCheckBox2';
  isChecked: boolean = false;

}
```

HTML :

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isChecked">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="isChecked">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

[image: Errors]

I still get those errors and i really dont know why. Myabe I'm the dumbest person alive.
Moreover, other component seems to work fine i just have trouble with the mat-checkbox.

**Update 2 :**

So, after openning the same exact project with WebStorm, everything is working fine.
Maybe it has something to do with VsCode and especially with the angular extension.
I will try to do a proper reinstallation of VsCode later.

**Last Update :**

Well, after uninstalling / installing Vscode fixed the issue. Simple as that.

Comment: Please, upload an stackblitz with your code, I more details about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've likely not imported `MatCheckboxModule` properly.

The component that this template belongs to needs to be declared in the same module where `MatCheckboxModule` is imported.

In a basic application this means:

`app.component.html`:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="isChecked">CheckBox</mat-checkbox>
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  protected isChecked: boolean = true;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e3xwbt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I dont think i did anything wrong when it comes to the importation of the module. I posted an update where i create a new project and i still have the same issue (I posted more code maybe you can check that out).

Comment: @DryPotato54 It appears you have solved the problem yourself in the end :) There was nothing wrong with your code from what I can see so maybe it was just your IDE acting up a bit.